# number of substring which are whose anagrams are palindrome

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a string of digits, count the number of subwords (consistent subsequences) that are anagrams of any palindrome.

My attempt in Python:

```
def ispalin(s):
    if len(s)%2==0:
        for i in s:
            if s.count(i)%2!=0:
                return False
    else:
        sum =0
        for i in set(s):
            if s.count(i)%2==1:
                sum = sum+1
        if sum == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    return True

def solution(S):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    count=len(S)
    for i in range(len(S)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(S)):
            if ispalin(S[i:j+1]):
                count=count+1

    return count
```

**i/o format**

```
For example, given:

    S = "02002"
the function should return 11. 
these are 11 substrings whose anagrams are palindrome
"0", "2", "0", "0", "2", "00", "020", "200", "002", "2002", "02002"
```

It is giving time limit exceeded for big strings. How can I optimize the above code?

**i bet there exists a better solution than this here is the proof** 
[image][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x3Jq.png

Comment: `s.count(i)` I would use `collections.Counter` for better speed. Can you add some test input & outputs?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre updated test cases, btw its complexity is o(n)3  we have to reduce the time complexity

Comment: @OmG there a solution exists in o(n) i bet , but i don't know for sure for now

Comment: In this case the solution should be based on some kind of permutation counting. You cannot iterate through all subwords in a linear time, since there are O(N^2) of them.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 yes hell of math in this

Comment: @bosey - bet all you want, you're not going to get an O(n) solution for this as you need to check every substring of a string and if there was a way to do it on general computers in linear time we'd all know about it a long time ago. The best you may hope for is O(n+L) using suffix trees or something similar.

Comment: @zwer will you bet now by looking at below voted solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an O(n) solution for this problem. The first thing to notice is, a substring is anagram of any palindrome if number of its including digits be even or at most one odd exist. e.g. "20020" is anagram of plaindrome because number of '2's is even and number of '0's is odd(at most one odd) while "200202" is not ok.

So the only thing we need to keep is parity of number of digits not sum of them. we can use a 10-bit number to show the parities of all digits. Starting from 0 each time we visit a digit in string, we can xor the parity number with (2^digit). following your example for "02002" here is the parity numbers generated by iterating through the string in binary format:

```
parity_array = {0000000000, 0000000001, 0000000101, 0000000100, 0000000101 0000000001}
```

Now we need to count the number of anagrams in linear time. Iterating over the parity_array we use another array of size 1024 (let's call it memo) to keep the number of times we visit a specific number in parity_array. As I mentioned before the substring is ok if and only if the number of 1 bits in their binary parity representation be at most 1. So for each member of parity_array we need to check and add 11 elements in memo having xor with current parity_array value equal to: {0 or 1 or 2 or 4 or 8 ... or 1024} and sum up the results.
The total complexity is O(n).

**Edit:**
I added C++ code for what I explained above. I can also add python code, if you want:

```
string sample = "02002";
int parity = 0;
vector<int> parity_array;
parity_array.push_back(parity);
for(int i=0; i<sample.size(); ++i){
    parity ^= 1<<(sample[i]-'0');
    parity_array.push_back(parity);
}
int memo[1025] = {0};
int res=0;
for(int i=0;i<parity_array.size();++i){
    for(int j=-1;j<10;++j)
        res += memo[(1<<j)^parity_array[i]];
    memo[parity_array[i]]++;
}
cout<<res<<endl;
```

Comment: can you give your soln in python or any lang

Comment: @ArgusMalware I added C++ code for the solution. I can also provide python code if you want.

Comment: @Alireza Could you please explain the second for loop more descriptively?

Comment: Putting this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515296/return-count-of-scatter-palindrome-of-a-string) here as it has a better explanation of the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get quadratic complexity using O(n) of memory.

Make array[0..9] of digit counters (or use another data structure convenient for Python)

Walk through the string, increment counter for current digit and add modified array to the list. After that list will contain "cumulative sums" - counts for every digit upto every index (for example, five 2's before 40-th string entry)

Now to get count for digit between i-th and j-th entries, just subtract `C[j][digit] - C[i][digit]`

Interesting question - does better complexity solution exist?

Comment: In terms of code, if I got the explanation right, I'd suggest the following: `from collections import Counter; C = [Counter(s[:i + 1]) for i in range(len(s))]`.

Comment: @MBo your efforts appreciated but i need O(N) and yes it exists

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 i think counter internally will take the same complexity and again i have to iterate counter to check for length of frequency of character for checking its palindrome or not

Comment: @bosey yes - I'm not proposing something new, just giving code that does what was described in words.

Comment: @MBo I added an O(n) solution